# Upload document to SharePoint using CronTab

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to upload files to SharePoint thru CronTab. Please guide me to achieve this.

Please let me know is it possible to do using scripting.

Thanks,
Rohit

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options to upload files to SharePoint and depends on what option crontab supports.

You can use
1. WebServices
2. Using client side .Net code
3. it could be using webdev

If you could explain here what kind of external integration features crontab supports it would be easier to provide you best solution for your question.